# Ceph Openstack HA installation with maas and juju but partially on physical servers and few on virtual machines

Tags: juju, kvm-virtualization, openstack, ceph, high-availability

I am planning to deploy [OpenStackHA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA) which 28 servers, which is quit a lot for me. So i am thinking to put up few of roles like `rabbitmq`, `mysql`, `cloud controller`, `horizon` on virtual machines on `KVM might`. And `ceph`, network node and compute nodes on physical servers.
Is it possible to implement OpenStack in such a way? Any precautionary steps that should be taken?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely possible and a valid solution to paring down the number of machines needed for an HA deployment of OpenStack. The latest version of MAAS, available in the cloud-archive, has support for "vMAAS" or Virtual MAAS, which gives MAAS the power to drive virtual machines in addition to physical ones.